# Python SSLError: VERSION_TOO_LOW

Tags: python, ssl, urllib, python-3.6

I'm having some trouble using urllib to fetch some web content on my Debian server. I use the following code to get the contents of most websites without problems:

```
import urllib.request as request
url = 'https://www.metal-archives.com/'
req = request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': "foobar"})
response = request.urlopen(req)
response.read()
```

However, if the website is using an older encryption protocol, the `urlopen` function will throw the following error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: VERSION_TOO_LOW] version too low (_ssl.c:748)
```

I have found a way to work around this problem, consisting in using an SSL context and passing it as an argument to the `urlopen` function, so the previous code would have to be modified:

```
...
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
response = request.urlopen(req, context=context)
...
```

Which will work, provided the protocol specified matches the website I'm trying to access. However, this does not seem like the best solution since:

1. If the site owners ever update their cryptography methods, the code will stop working
2. The code above will only work for this site, and I would have to create special cases for every website I visit in the entire program, since everyone could be using a different version of the protocol. That would lead to pretty messy code
3. The first solution I posted (the one without the ssl context) oddly seems to work on my ArchLinux machine, even though they both have the same versions of everything

Does anyone know about a generic solution that would work for every TLS version? Am I missing something here?

PS: For completeness, I will add that I'm using Debian 9, python v3.6.2, openssl v1.1.0f and urllib3 v1.22

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've opted to wrap the method call inside a try-except, so I can use the older SSL version as fallback. The final code is this:

```
url = 'https://www.metal-archives.com'
req = request.Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "foobar"})
try:
    response = request.urlopen(req)
except (ssl.SSLError, URLError):
    # Try to use the older TLSv1 to see if we can fix the problem
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    response = request.urlopen(req, context=context)
```

I have only tested this code on a dozen websites and it seems to work so far, but I'm not sure it will work every time. Also, this solution seems inefficient, since it needs two http requests, which can be very slow.

Improvements are still welcome :)